# Viewport2DVisual3D Frame created is not visible

Tags: wpf, frame, visible, viewport3d

Hi all i have a frame code as such

```
<Frame Name="wow" Width="1200" Height="600" ></Frame>
```

When i click on a `button`, it loads it with a url as such

```
wow.Source=(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
```

It works when i throw it into a `grid`, it appears just fine however when i throw it into a `viewport2dvisual3d` container, it doesn't appear.

```
  <Viewport2DVisual3D.Visual >
    <Grid Width="1200" Height="600" Name="frontPanel" Background="Blue">
      <Frame Name="wow" Width="1200" Height="600" ></Frame>            
        </Grid>                   
          </Viewport2DVisual3D.Visual>
```

The `frame` isn't even visible. I do see my mouse changing to a loading symbol for a few seconds but i still cant seem to see the frame.

Is this a bug? or do i have to do something to make the frame appear in a `viewport2dvisual3d` which is within a viewport 3d?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far what I can see you are missing the `Geometry` and the `Material` for `Viewport2DVisual3D` and `Viewport2DVisual3D.IsVisualHostMaterial` for `Material`

full example for Viewport2DVisual3D object

```
    <Viewport2DVisual3D>
        <Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
            <MeshGeometry3D Positions="-1,1,0 -1,-1,0 1,-1,0 1,1,0"
                            TextureCoordinates="0,0 0,1 1,1 1,0"
                            TriangleIndices="0 1 2 0 2 3" />
        </Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
        <Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>
            <DiffuseMaterial Viewport2DVisual3D.IsVisualHostMaterial="True" />
        </Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>
            <Grid Width="1200" Height="600" Name="frontPanel" Background="Blue">
               <Frame Name="wow" Width="1200" Height="600" ></Frame>
            </Grid>
    </Viewport2DVisual3D>
```